# My Graphql App from Developer Tools, I see that it always fetch, is this correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

My Graphql works very well.
Query, Create, Anyway I see that it always fetch (Developer Tools -> Network).
Is this correct? or I have to fix something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working fine then there is no problem. The browser is using `fetch` to communicate with the back-end.